# Is there a good way to add a Document Listener to a Dynamically created JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I am reading in information from an xml file where i have no idea how much information is there until i read it in. I dynamically create Jtextfields and can get the information to appear on them. I am trying to add a documentlistener to those text fields so that a user can change the data and it will automatically update the xml file every time a number is changed. The problem is that there is no reference to the JTextField to get the text from and it is causing a compiler error. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory style setup.

Basically, create a method or class that will create a `JTextField`.  Pass it the reference to the node that it will be responsible for.

Create the text field and register the `DocumentListener` to it...although, I'd be wary about using a `DocumentListener` personally, maybe a `ActionListener` and/or `FocusListener` might be more suitable, but hay.

Comment: @Doug B by default xml structure is designated for table or tree structure, use JTable or JTree